# how to refresh parent from child if parent is account detail page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, standard-objects

I have a use case to add a custom button on account detail page, on click of which a VF page opens up in which i will input value say salary and that will update the account record. Now what i want is that on saving the salary in my VF page i want to refresh the parent(i.e. the account record detail page) and then close the child.
I have tried all the option that was given in many related Q&A but nothing worked for me.

Did anybody faced this issue..

P.S. when i am doing this from one VF page to another VF page than the parent is getting refreshed, i suppose there is some problem with standard detail page where i have the button.

Comment: Ok so just so I understand, you click the button from the standard account page, which opens VF page in a new window?  And on update of the salary, you want to close the popup window (your VF page) and refresh the standard account page.

Comment: Yes.. exactly...

Comment: ok added something that hopefully helps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your VF page, you just need to add a bit of javascript in the oncomplete of your commandbutton

**Your button**

```
<apex:commandButton value="saveSalary" action="{!yourSaveMethod}" oncomplete="myClose();"/>
```

**JS method**

```
function myClose(){
    window.opener.location.href="/{!$CurrentPage.parameters.yourAccountIdParamName}";
    window.top.close();
    //you could also use self.close();    
}
```

This is assuming you used a param to pass the accountID to the VF page.

Comment: Great, glad to help :)

Comment: I want to add something in here... i also used the same method that u have written but it was not working as my development mode was on. So i suppose that is also a new learning for me. :)

Comment: @sfdc_ninja Awesome answer .

Comment: @sfdc_ninja window.opener.location.href is not working in IE. In mozilla and chrome it works fine but not in IE. any change required in this?

Comment: I have been using same code it works with firefox , chrome but in IE it opens a new tab.